# R statistics assessing probability of cases. What is the chance in bridge ...

Tags: r, statistics, probability, probability-theory

What is the chance that the first five cards chosen from a deck of 52(bridge/poker) cards will contain Two(only two) cards of the same denomination(two 3's for example)?
How can we solve the following problem by resampling method in R

Answer (score 2):

On Wikipedia, they have the [formula for finding the probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) for two alike cards, three of a kind, etc.. I'd use that formula.